# Sitecore Ucommerce - How to access RavenDB Studio

Tags: sitecore, ravendb-studio, sitecore-ucommerce

I need to access the data in RavenDB shipped with Ucommerce in Sitecore application. The Ucommerce doc page says you can do it.

http://docs.ucommerce.net/ucommerce/v7.1/manage-ucommerce/access-ravendb-studio.html

I set the binding for the port 1337

I tried http://mysite:1337 and http://mysite:1337/databases

I set NETWORK SERVICES as Administrator and recycled the AppPool

But it does not seem to work.
I cannot figure out what exactly should I do for it.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you perform all the steps outlined in article?

If you did there are a few extra things you can check:

- Make sure the app pool runs with an identity which is in the admin group (The identity should be LocalSystem).
- After you change the configuration, make sure you recycle the app pool to force it to pick up the new configuration
- Then type {web site url}:1337 (there should be no binding on port 1337)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Søren Spelling Lund, I will check for it tomorrow. By the way, did you actually managed to open it?

Comment: I did indeed 

Comment: I put the Network Services to Administrators group, recycled the app pool, typed http:// mysite.com:1337 and got 'This site can’t be reached mysite.com refused to connect'. Do I need to create a binding in IIS for port 1337? Do I need to create a site definition in Sitecore config?

Comment: Shouldn't need anything else. Could you try cross posting to http://eureka.ucommerce.net? That's where the product team hangs out :)

Comment: Søren Spelling Lund, the app pool identity should be Local System, then by typing http://siteurl:1337 you will access ravenDB studio. So if you adapt your answer within 24 hours, I will accept it.